# why is this behaviour with MACRO?

Tags: c, macros

I've the following code.if i give control_word as 6 why if condition evaluates to true and enters inside if block?what exactly is happening here?

```
#define MACRO1 0x01
#define MACRO2 0x02
#define MACRO4 0x04
#define MACRO3 MACRO1 | MACRO2
#define MACRO7 MACRO4 | MACRO3

int main()
{
    if(control_word == MACRO3 || control_word == MACRO7)
    {
        /*DO SOME OPERATION*/
    }
    else
    {
        /*DO SOMETHING ELSE */
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not a question about macros.  You can just perform all the substitutions, and you'll see why you get that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
control_word == MACRO3 || control_word == MACRO7
```

expands to

```
control_word == MACRO1 | MACRO2 || control_word == MACRO4 | MACRO3
```

which eventually expands to

```
control_word == 1 | 2 || control_word == 4 | 1 | 2
```

looking at the [precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B), you see that operator `==` has higher precendence than `|`, which is higher than `||`, so the evaluation is:

```
((control_word == 1) | 2) || ((control_word == 4) | 1 | 2)
```

which evaluates to

```
((6 == 1) | 2) || ((6 == 4) | 1 | 2)
```

which is (`6==1` is `false`, which is treated as 0 in the arithmetic expression -- same for `6==4`)

```
((0 | 2) || (0 | 1 | 2)
```

which is

```
2 || 3
```

which is

```
true
```

as 2 and 3 are treated as `true` (non-zero), so you enter the `if` block, not the `else`

To preserve the (presumed) intent (and get the result you exprected) you need to protect the expansion of the macros by wrapping their definition in parentheses -- note that this is *always* a good idea to avoid the dissonance between what you think and what is actually happening.

Answer (score 11):

The precedence of the | and == operators is not that you think it is. Moral: always parenthesize your macros!

```
#define MACRO3 (MACRO1 | MACRO2)
#define MACRO7 (MACRO4 | MACRO3)
```

So what happens is the expression expands to

```
control_word == 0x01 | 0x02 || control_word == 0x01 | 0x02  | 0x04
```

which in turn forms

```
(control_word == 1) | 2 || (control_word == 7) | 6)
```

that is

```
0 | 2 || 0 | 6
```

so all in all it's

```
2 || 6
```

which is interpreted by C as "true or true", and that yields true.

Comment: Yes i agree parenthesis solves the problem.can you please explain how it entered if block?What is the exact behavior here?

Comment: It's **not** a precedence issue between _|_ and _||_, it's _==_ and _|_. See this [precedence chart](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html) and consider what happens when changing the code to: `if((control_word == MACRO3) || (control_word == MACRO7))`